# response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"); is not setting in Jsp

Tags: jsp, response

I'm trying to set response header in JSP file with below line

```
response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```

but when i print value of contains header it is returning false,also verified from devtools,no header has been set for "X-Content-Type-Options".

```
System.out.println("check if header has value " +response.containsHeader("X-Content-Type-Options"));
```

if I set in filter servlet class it's adding a response header, but that is causing other issues in existing applications as that header will set to every page
, can anyone help me to set in JSP file.

Comment: Might you be trying to set the header after the response has been committed? If so, that won't work and you'll need to set the header earlier.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks for the response,  yes looks like we can not edit the response header once we dispatch form the filter class, so I added  in filter class with the condition to check URI, so its adding header only for the required page